# Pivot without number gets null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, null, pivot

I've tried writing a simple pivot function with SQL. My main problem is that all the tables involved have no numbers in them. I think that this is the main reason I get only one result and the rest is NULL even though some of the cells have data in them.
This is my function:

```
SELECT  Inspector, ShiftManager, ForkliftOperator, CalibrationOperator, sorted
FROM    (SELECT LHAPP_OWNER.dbo.Personnel.FirstName + ' ' + LHAPP_OWNER.dbo.Personnel.LastName
            AS name, LHAPP_OWNER.dbo.PersonnelGroup.PersonnelGroup
     FROM   MachineGroup
            INNER JOIN _MG_CurrentEmployee ON MachineGroup.MachineGroupID = _MG_CurrentEmployee.MachineGroupID
            INNER JOIN LHAPP_OWNER.dbo.PersonnelGroup ON _MG_CurrentEmployee.PerssonelGroupID = LHAPP_OWNER.dbo.PersonnelGroup.PersonnelGroupID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN LHAPP_OWNER.dbo.Personnel ON _MG_CurrentEmployee.PerssonelID = LHAPP_OWNER.dbo.Personnel.PersonnelID
     WHERE  (MachineGroup.MachineGroup = N'Line 1')) tbl PIVOT
( MIN(name) FOR PersonnelGroup IN (Inspector, ShiftManager, ForkliftOperator, CalibrationOperator, sorted) ) tbl2
```

I didn't know what to do with the name so I just gave it MIN. I know it's probably wrong.
Could someone give me a hand here?

My main Table of the inner select looks like this:

```
name               ||     PersonnelGroup 
---------------------------------------
ron roni           ||        Inspector
Lighthouse Systems ||   Shift Manager
gali logi          ||    Forklift Operator
NULL               ||    Calibration Operator
NULL               ||             sorted
```

After the function I get this:

```
Inspector|ShiftManager|ForkliftOperator|CalibrationOperator|Sorted
------------------------------------------------------------------------
ron roni |      NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL
```

Comment: what RDMS and version are you trying to use. It looks like sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK now. I found out the problem. Some of the PersonnelGroup names had two words in them and I looked for one word combining the tow words and so it didn't find any answers. For example, I changed 'ShiftManager' into '[Shift Manager]'